# how to get gallery image path with an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

In my android application, I am trying to let the user select a gallery image and show a high-quality image in another activity. is there a way to get an absolute path from URI? or is there an efficient way to do this?

This function opens the gallery and lets the user select an image:

```
    private fun getGalleryImage() {
        val galleryImageIntent =
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)

        if (galleryImageIntent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(galleryImageIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE)
        }
    }
```

And the following gets the result, but I am not sure how to get the image path

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {   

            startActivity(
                Intent(context, ImageViewActivity::class.java).putExtra(
                    "imagePath",
                    data?.data?.toString()
                )
            )

        } else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

Here is my ImageViewActivity:

```
class ImageViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view)

        backBtn.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }

        val imagePath = intent?.extras?.get("imagePath")
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath?.toString())?.also { bitmap ->
            imageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried sending the bitmap itself to my ImageViewActivity but it keeps crashing, and from what I read online, it is not possible to send large amount of data to an Activity.

Comment: You should open an input stream for the obtained uri. So for imagePath?.toString(). And then use BitmapFactory.decodeStream().

Comment: @blackapps Thanks that worked!